# Put a instagram-like Button on a iOs TabBar

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar

I search but I havn't found yet a way to add a button in a `storyBoard` on a `tabBar`, a button that will pop up a view and don't show the actual tabBar (like the add Photo button on Instagram).

Comment: i believe you would have to go for custom tab bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options:

1. Create your own custom tab bar and add UIButton as a subview on it
2. Save time and effort and integrate a library into your code that doing it for you. [This](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar) library is a good choice